# Send file as binary in axios

Tags: file-upload, axios, stream

I have a file upload API. It works fine when I upload a file using the binary option using postman as seen in the screenshot below.

[image]

But when I try to call this post request via axios, the file seems to be corrupted.
Can someone guide me on how to send file as binary as seen in postman.

```
    let pickFrom = path.join(__dirname, '../sampleVideos', path.basename(filename));
    
    let formData = new FormData();
    
    formData.append('file', fs.createReadStream(pickFrom));
    
    const getLength = promisify(formData.getLength.bind(formData))
    const contentLength = await getLength()
    let config = {

        headers : {
            'content-length': contentLength,
            ...formData.getHeaders()
        },
        maxBodyLength: Infinity
    }
    
    
    let url = domain + '/api/video/upload/' + videometa._id;    
    const response =  axios.post(`${url}`, formData, config);
```